# Send event to another class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

in my web react project i have two class one "Menu" return the Menu for my dashboard (the links to change the pages "Home" , "messages" ....) and another one "Box" for show the pages (it's the container of my website pages ) so my question is  how the page when i click button ?.

```js
 class menu(){
        render(){
           return(<button>click to go to home</button>) ;
        }
   
   }
   
   class box(){
       render (){
          return(<Home>this is  the home</Home>) ; 
       }  }
```

Comment: Hi, please add some more examples of your code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parent component that has the page property and the setPage method.

Inside that component, render the toolbar and the pages. The toolbar should accept a prop that'll called onClickPage that should dispatch the setPage. For example:

```
const [page, setPage] = React.useState("dashboard");


....

<Toolbar onClickPage={page => setPage(page)} />
<Pages page={page} />
```

This is what's called Lifting the state up (https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) I suggest you to read their docs. It's very beginners friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If your main problem is to navigate between pages you can easily achieve this by using react-router.
https://reactrouter.com